# Появление блока при скроле экрана более чем на 200px от верхнего края страницы

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть скрытый див .scroll, нужно на jQuery сделать появление этого блока при скроле экрана более чем на 200px от верхнего края страницы. При скролле обратно к верху экрана блок должен снова исчезать.

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="scroll"> text </div>

  <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>
</body>
```

CSS

```
    .scroll {
    color: red;
    border-width: 1px;
    float: right;
    border-style: solid;
    background: black;
    width: 70px;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала добавьте вашему классу scroll модификаторы:

```
position: fixed;
top:200px;
left:100px;
```

Для того, чтобы ваш объект не проскроливался вместе со всей страницей, хотя если вам этот эффект не нужен, то можно этого не делать.
Далее создайте простой скрипт для проверки скроллинга страницы:

```
$(document).on("scroll", window, function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop()>200) 
    {
        $(".scroll").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".scroll").hide();
    }
    });
```

Comment: Мне еще нужно, чтобы объект прилипал к правому краю, а left:100px этому мешает) а вместо top:200px, margin-top: 200px; нельзя было писать? Попробовал скрипт, ничего не происходит, а то что display: none; установлено не мешает скрипту?

Comment: @Степан, приношу извинения, слегка сбил вас, да можно left и top задать 0, чтобы позиционировать, как вам будет удобнее. А на счет display: none, оно не мешает, так как я писал используя ваш класс. У вас точно длина страницы превышает размер окна браузера? Для теста укажите height для тега body или html равный, например, 5000px

Comment: Длинна страницы большая, сделал, скрипт в был перед дивом, перенес в конец. Все, теперь все понял, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
   if($(window).scrollTop()>=200) {
     $('div.scroll').fadeIn(200);
   } else {
     $('div.scroll').fadeOut(200);
   }
});
```

Comment: не знаю, что я делаю не так, но не работает) display: none; не может мешать?

Comment: @Степан не мешает

Comment: разобрался, так тоже работает, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант:

```js
var isScrolling=false;

$(window).on("DOMMouseScroll mousewheel",function(e){

    if(!isScrolling){
        isScrolling=true;

        var delta = parseInt(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -e.originalEvent.detail);

        if (delta >= 0) {
            isScrolling=false;

            $('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');

        }else {

            if($(window).scrollTop()>200){
                $('.scroll').addClass('hidden');
            }

            isScrolling=false;

        }
    }

});
```

```css
.scroll {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
    height: 50px;
 z-index: 8000;
 background: #000;

 transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transform: translateY(-50px);
}

.hidden {
    transform: translateY(0px);
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>

  
  <div class="scroll">
    
  </div>
```

Изначально скрытый блок, при скролле вниз - появляется, обратный скролл - исчезает.

Comment: зачем так сложно?

Comment: да, я думаю для меня это будет сложно, я простые то примеры пока не реализовал))